# How to disable 302 redirect in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that I need to run behind a reverse proxy. The reverse proxy runs on the same machine as the Spring Boot application, but it uses a different port.

The Spring Boot application, when accessed thrugh the proxy, returns a 302 redirect. Based on what I have learned from Spring documentation, this is standard -- especially when Spring Security is used. The problem is that one reason why I am using a reverse proxy is because I am running several applications on my deployment machine and I want only one open port on that machine. Consequently, my Spring Boot application redirects my browser to a closed port, which in turn causes various failures to occur.

I need to stop my Spring Boot application from responding with 302 redirects. I am pretty sure it is pssible, but it is unclear from the documentation how to do this.

Can someone please either tell me how to disable 302 redirects on Spring Boot, or point me to some examples of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Standard way may be not preventing redirect, but redirecting to right port.

- Configure the reverse proxy to send [`X-Forwarded-Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host) (or `X-Forwarded-Port`) header.
- Configure Spring Boot properties [`server.forward-headers-strategy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.use-behind-a-proxy-server) to `NATIVE`.

Comment: Actually, this does not appear to work. I have set the reverse proxy to add both X-Forwarded-Host and X-Forwarded-Port to the host and port of my reverse proxy (localhost and the port). I also added the server.forward.header.strategy value (NATIVE) in Sprong Boot properties. I am still getting 302 redirect responses. The Spring Boot app seems to be ignoring the headers.